# what is DH keypair exception and how to resolve that

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, spring-social

I am getting following exception **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair**
Background: I have a java desktop application where I do login with facebook. I have used HttpServer in my code to get the response from facebook. So, when I was trying to login with face book app was giving SSLHandshake exception. So, I generated jssecacerts using InstallCert.java and put the 'jssecacerts' file in the /lib/security. So, now when I'm trying to login with facebook I am getting this exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

why it is happening and how to resolve it? do I need to do something in the HttpServer instance that I have used to get the response from the facebook?

Comment: do you have more of that error message / stack trace? The root cause may be indicated further down.

Comment: Thilo here is the last exception from stack trace:    Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)    how to increase the range of prime size? will it solve the problem?

Comment: Seems like its a bug in Java (see linked thread), apparently  fixed in recent Java updates. What JVM are you using? Try updating it if possible.